# See all changed and new files in p4v

Tags: perforce, p4v

Is there a way to see all changed files in p4v without out having to trawl through the directory tree in the workspace view?

I am much more familiar with git and I am essentially looking for `git status` at the top level of a repository. I want to be able to see this in p4v rather than the p4 command line tool which most search results seem to turn up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Perforce's standard "check out" workflow, all the changed files are always in your pending changelist(s) in the right hand pane.

If you're modifying files without checking them out (note that this negates many of Perforce's benefits relative to git), use the "Reconcile offline work" feature to do a `git status`-like scan of the local tree.  https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4v/Content/P4V/using.offline.html

Comment: Thank you! I was going mad trying to find this.
I need to have a look at checking stuff out so I don't get myself into this mess again.

Comment: If you turn off the "allwrite" option in your workspace, files that aren't checked out are read-only, which will help you remember to check them out before saving them.  If your IDE has a plugin that will automatically `p4 edit` a file before you save it, you barely have to think about it.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2019 primarily, so I expect finding something shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Perforce has an official plugin for Visual Studio: https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-plugin-visual-studio-p4vs